# Lost extended partition after installing windows

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, ext4, ext3

I was using Ubuntu 13.04 and the hard disk was partitioned as follows:

- Primary Ext4 (250GB)
- Linux Extended (250GB) and Ext3 or Ext4 logical partition
- Linux Swap (4GB)

I have installed Windows 7, and during the installation I have deleted the Linux Primary partition and created windows NTFS primary partition on its place and installed windows 7 on it. I thought that using any Ext3/4 reader I can extract the data on my logical partition but all the tools I used only view the Extended partition with un-located space!! as there is no logical partition at all. I have tried to boot to Ubuntu using the live CD but it didn't mount the partition and even when I used the default partitiion management tool it showed the same result of extended partition with un-located space.

Please help me to recover the data in the extended partition.

Answer (score 1):

If Windows has taken over the space used by that partition, your only hope is to use something like [PhotoRec,](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) which can recover individual files. You should recover the files to a different physical disk to avoid the (significant) possibility of trashing one file while you recover another one. Note that PhotoRec is unlikely to recover your filenames, so you'll need to spend a lot of time sorting through the files and renaming them.

If Windows has left your extended partition's space alone, you might be able to recover it using [TestDisk.](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) This program will search for "lost" partitions and recover them whole, so you'll then be able to mount the partition and copy files off it normally. Obviously, this is a much better solution than PhotoRec, so you should try it first if GParted or other partitioning software shows the space previously occupied by Linux to be unoccupied.